# custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- myapp(LoadError)

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

i get the above error, all i did was install rvm and update to ruby 1.9.2 from the default ruby that you get with mac.

all my gems appear in the gem list but do i need to specify a path somewhere?

cheers,

glenno.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check that you have the gems installed `gem list` If not, install as usual `gem install whatever` or if you want a specific version `gem install whatever -v 1.2.3` Or if you have bundler in your project (ie Rails), it's just `bundle install`

If you have all the gems, then this is probably a local file, and you're probably coming from Ruby version < 1.9, you need to either fix your `$LOAD_PATH` (which will depend on too many factors for me to explain here), or specify the full path to the file you want `File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/myapp'`

Otherwise, you need to give more info, like what version you used to be running, what `myapp` is, and where it is in relation to your file.

Comment: Hi, i think its the 2nd point, my gem list is good, i come from ruby on mac osx 1.8.7 installed rvm to my home drive then rvm install ruby 1.9.2. how do i fix my load path, is that in my profile or in the file that gives the error which is custom_require??

Comment: Your load path will be different for every application. Rubygems already manages the load path for your gems, so I'll assume myapp is a local file that you want to require relatively to the file it is being required from. In this case, You can do the `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/myapp'` (assuming they are in the same dir). Or you can add the root of your app to the load path, something like this `$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)` (assuming this file is in root, and is first file loaded), then require all of your files relative to the root.

Comment: sorry joshua, i'm new to osx, where do i add the file path to? let me give you some context, mongoblog is the project, inside of it im running rackup config.ru which launches myapp.rb. do i place the require file.dirname in the config.ru file or myapp.rb?

Comment: crap, i added the path to the config file, now i'm getting a different error. dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- views/layout (LoadError)

Comment: I would put the second example `$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)` in the config. Your error implies that views is not a directory in the config (or you went with the first example). In that case, you need to specify the path to layout from the root (possibly `require "app/views/layout"`) 

BTW, if this is Rails, you're probably doing something wrong, because all of this should already be handled for you.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek - I am trying to learn Rspec from a book, using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rspec 2.0.0. I installed every single gem per the book, ran the code in Eclipse with DLTK. I get the error - `C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in gem_original_require': no such file to load -- spec (LoadError)`. The book does not even mention anything about spec. I can't get spec gem for this because spec gem was created after the book was published. So there is no spec gem for 1.8.7. Please advise what I can do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was rvm issue, I was using rvm 1.9 when i changed it to 1.8, migration worked.

rvm use 1.8

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was converting to Cygwin64.  The Cygwin directory name changed and Ruby upgraded to 1.9.  After I fixed the Cygwin directory name, the second solution worked.  Or at least got past this problem:

require File.dirname(**FILE**) + '/myapp.rb'