# Require 'Filename' in irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I'm following along with a book that's building an Sinatra app with several mysql database tables. It gave me instructions to make a mysql database , which I did, and then it told me to go into IRB and do

```
require 'tinyclone'
```

According to the book, entering that command will "require the necessary classes for creating the database tables" after which I was supposed to run

```
Datamapper.auto_migrate!
```

However, when I tried to do require 'tinyclone' I got this error

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- tinyclone
    from /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I opened in the IRB session in the same directory where tinyclone.rb resides, so I don't think that's the problem.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117066/custom-require-rb36in-require-no-such-file-to-load-myapploaderror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excepte include  the full path, ruby 1.9 introduces a new way to do that.

```
require_relative 'tinyclone'
```

This will require the tinyclone.rb file in the relative directory of the current one.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the full path

require '/Users/me/sites/cloning/tinyclone.rb'

Comment: Otherwise you can specify using current directory usingn "./"

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify full path of the file, so you need to specify like below,

```
require './tinyclone'
```

or you can specify full path like below,

```
require '/home/user/tinyclone'
```