# Error in running Ruby on thrift

Tags: ruby, rubygems, thrift

I am unable to run thrift for ruby.Getting error like this[image]

Installed sudo gem install thrift
Ruby version 1.9.3
Thrift version 0.9.1
when ever tried to run any ruby file(client.rb,server.rb or any ruby file , getting above error)

Answer (score 0):

This below link will be more helpful to run your application

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117066/custom-require-rb36in-require-no-such-file-to-load-myapploaderror)