# cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to setup my database for Heroku. I've tried gem install bundler/ bundle install and that installs fine. However I still get this error. Any advice? Thanks!

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ mycapstoneeventbrighter... up, run.2960
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /app/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rake:3:in `load'
from /app/bin/rake:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: whats on line 36 of custom_require.rb?

Comment: actually yours is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117066/custom-require-rb36in-require-no-such-file-to-load-myapploaderror

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the way you linked and i still have the same error. Would it be the ruby version? It says me heroku toolbelt should run ruby/2.1.2. But it is obviously raking /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/. Sorry I'm a bit new at this.

Comment: can you do a ```which rbenv``` then ```which heroku``` followed by ```echo $PATH``` order of command sis not important. I just need the output. You need to install another version of Ruby as the error says. On Nix/mac I use rbenv https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv then you can install heroku inside the virtual ruby environment without tinkering with the currently installed ruby version.

Comment: thanks for the help Vangel! I don't know what I did but it eventually worked.

Comment: I am not surprised. I have heard that on more than one occasion :) usually something is stuck in bash environment which goes away when you reboot.